# sns/matplotlib clustermap/heatmap generates weird notches in individual cells

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap using sns.clustermap and getting following type of notches when saved using savefig. Has anybody seen this kind of errors?

[image]

I tried both option: saving to pdf file with rasterized=True and saving directly to png.

With dpi=300, I still get notches:
[image]

Comment: My data is a [7841 rows x 177 columns] binary matrix (1 for light color and 0 for dark). I used default dpi. Let me try with different dpi. I saved the figure with figsize parameter (25, 10).

Comment: With so many rows/columns, it is possible that the notches are part of your data.  Are they still there when you zoom in a lot?

Comment: Yes. I tried with dpi=300. Still I see notches. See new fig. Here it can be easily seen the span for individual column (fig is zoom in). So these small notches can not be a part of the data.

Comment: With dpi=600, I still get few notches. But number of notches reduced.

Comment: I am using matplotlib 3.3.2 seaborn  0.9.0

Comment: You really should try to upgrade both.   If that doesn't help, you could intend to create a reproducible example with generated test data. Can you confirm you don't see the notches while plotting in a window? And you do seem them when saving to png?

Comment: I tried on a different system with matplotlib 3.3.3 and seaborn 0.11.1. The notches continue.

Comment: When I save using pdf with rasterized=False, I do not get the notches. However, that has another issue https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/373 which I want to avoid.

Comment: @JohanC, I see the notches while plotting in a window (i.e. from the interpreter I called plt.show().